# How to select vertical ListView item based on its current position using XAML and C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to do something tricky. I want to select a list item by determining whether the `ScrollViewer` is scrolled and if the item is in the center of the `ScrollViewer`. I want to select an item when the user manually scrolls it to the center of a ListView. I do not want to scroll to the selected item, because that would be too easy, right?

Here's a drawing:

[image: Always Select the center item in a vertical ListView]

I've managed to detect whether the scroller has been scrolled. First I place a Loaded Event on the ListView in question "itemsList" and find the `ScrollViewer` type by traversing the visual tree to see if it has finished scrolling and tag the `ScrollViewer` to the ListView and handle the SelectionChanged event:

```
private void ItemsList_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var listView = (sender as ListView);
  if (listView != null)
  {
    var scrollers = FindVisualChildren<ScrollViewer>(sender as DependencyObject);
    var scrollView = scrollers.First();
    if (scrollView != null)
    {
      scrollView.Tag = listView;
      scrollView.ViewChanged += ScrollViewOnViewChanged;
      listView.SelectionChanged += listView_SelectionChanged;
    }
  }
}

public IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
  if (depObj != null)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
      DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
      if (child != null && child is T)
      {
        yield return (T)child;
      }

      foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
      {
        yield return childOfChild;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I handle the `ScrollViewOnViewChanged` event where I determine if the scrollviewer is still scrolling. This is where I'm running into a few problems where I also need to determine the position of the `ListViewItem` and select it - I'd love some help here:

```
private void ScrollViewOnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //Debug.WriteLine("ScrollViewOnViewChanged + IsIntermediate="+e.IsIntermediate);

  var scrollviewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
  var listview = scrollviewer.Tag as ListView;

  if (!e.IsIntermediate)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("IsIntermediate = false");
    // TODO: Determine the center Item and set is as the selected item for this group.
  }
}
```

Then the `SelectionChanged` event where I make some magic happen:

```
void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("SelectionChanged");
}
```

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the item in the middle by using the method `InputHitTest` of `ScrollViewer`.

Example:

```
IInputElement element = scrollViewer.InputHitTest(
    new Point(scrollViewer.Width / 2, scrollViewer.Height / 2));
```

Comment: I'll experiment with this tomorrow and post my results. I may have a few follow-up questions.

Comment: IInputElement Interface doesn't seem to be exposed for WinRT. I'm looking for an equivalent right now.

Comment: Although this implementation would be super, WinRT does not have the IInputElement class, so I fiddled with this concept and was able to create a suitable hit test. Although I now need to create a cross-fade animation between the current and previous list item.

Comment: Does WinRT actually have the InputHitTest method? What is the return type?

Comment: No it does not. we need to define the UIElement, find either its parent or children and go from there.